# FacesContext.isPartialRequest()

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

The JSF 2.0 Specification mentions this method in several places, for example Section 2.2.2 Apply Request Values. The Java EE 6 API does not show that FacesContext has such a method. The API describes something different, starting with a call to FacesContext.getPartialViewContext(). Why the discrepancy?

Comment: do you have links to the exact documents/sites you read

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

Comment: Which statements are exactly made? Please, edit your question and attach the links to the concrete resources, also include the statements as quotes and a comparison between them.

Comment: I don't understand the need for all the hand-holding. The original post was quite clear. The JSF 2.0 Specification mentions "FacesContext.isPartialRequest()" in several places. The Java EE 6 API reveals that the FacesContext class has no such method.